# Save functionality with multi-datatype inputs

Tags: input-fields, data-tables, save, text-editor, autosave

I apologize if the question title seems unclear. I have a business application with multiple input/data types on the same screen:

1. A couple "basic" text input and dropdown menus. These fields are
   typically set/saved first, and everything else may be filled out
   later. Users have the ability to go back and change the values.
2. A single long text area (requiring a WYSIWYG)
3. An editable table, where one of the column fields includes a 500
   character max textarea

Given the different data types, what would you recommend for how to deal with the save functionality?

My initial thought was editable popups for the table rows (#3), since inline editing wouldn't work out well with the text area field. Similarly, would it make sense for the long text (#2) to be initially displayed as a read-only paragraph with an edit button that would bring up a WYSIWYG popup? If so, would auto-save be a consideration on such a field?
Since the last two parts are popups, I'm very tempted to have popup editing for basic fields (#1).

Would this make sense? Am I making things overly complicated?

Comment: This question probably results in "it depends" answers. Can you tell a little more about the content or context, or maybe add wireframes or screenshots?